# Run/Execute/Load JavaScript Source Using VC++ BHO

Tags: javascript, visual-c++, dom, web, bho

I am novice in developing BHO(Browser Helper Object).
Writing simple BHO which collect URLs from Google search result and insert GIF(BITMAP) after every URLs.
My BHO code is partially done and geting URLs too but URLS are not what i see on page:

Example:

If i search for "Driver Object"
Then I expect URLs like:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
```

BUT after DocumentComplete event i get URLs like:

```
http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fwindows%2Fhardware%2Fff548034%28v%3Dvs.85%29.aspx&ei=s6TmUvneH8eJrQeJ0YEQ&usg=AFQjCNGPT5rAp6Yw2givF35tAtkFEi7gjw
```

After Some study and analysis i come up with solution that it is possible using javascript to collect actual URLs instead of Google redirected URLs.
but i dont know how to execute JavaScript source(xyz.js) code file from VC++ BHO.

Thanks in advance.

```
hRes = m_WebBrowser2->get_Document(&pIDisp);
if (FAILED(hRes))
    return TRUE;

pHTMLDoc = (IHTMLDocument2 *)pIDisp;
IHTMLElementCollection *pMainCollection = NULL;
IHTMLElementCollection *pCollection = NULL;
hRes = pHTMLDoc->get_all(&pMainCollection);
if (FAILED(hRes))
{
    pHTMLDoc->Release();
    return TRUE;
}

IDispatch *pEmbdDisp = NULL;
IHTMLElementCollection *pEmbedCollection = NULL;
VARIANT varTag;
varTag.vt = VT_BSTR;
varTag.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"a");
hRes = pMainCollection->tags(varTag, &pEmbdDisp);
if (FAILED (hRes))
{
    goto CleanUp;
}

hRes = pEmbdDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElementCollection, (void **)&pEmbedCollection);
if (FAILED (hRes))
{
    if (pEmbdDisp)
    {
        pEmbdDisp->Release();
        pEmbdDisp = NULL;
    }

    goto CleanUp;
}

pCollection = pEmbedCollection;

//
//  Gel links count.
//
long lCount = 0;
hRes = pCollection->get_length(&lCount);
if (FAILED(hRes))
{
    OutputDebugStringW(L"pCollection->get_length...FAILED.");

    pCollection->Release();
    pHTMLDoc->Release();
    return TRUE;
}

BSTR bstr;
VARIANT varIndex;
varIndex.vt = VT_UINT;
VARIANT var2;
var2.vt = VT_UINT;

IHTMLElement *pElement = NULL;
for (int iIter = 0; iIter < lCount; iIter++)
{
    varIndex.lVal = iIter;
    var2.lVal = iIter;
    pElement = NULL;

    hRes = pCollection->item(var2, varIndex, &pDisp);
    if (FAILED(hRes))
        continue;
    hRes  = pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElement, (void **)&pElement);
    if (FAILED (hRes))
    {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"Disp->QueryInterface for IID_IHTMLElement...FAILED.");

        if (pDisp)
            pDisp->Release();
        continue;
    }

    IHTMLAnchorElement *pAnchElement = NULL;
    hRes = pElement->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLAnchorElement, (void **)&pAnchElement);
    if (FAILED (hRes))
    {
        if (pDisp)
        {
            pDisp->Release();
            pDisp = NULL;
        }
        continue;
    }

    hRes = pAnchElement->get_href(&bstr);
    //
    //  bstr is the URL
    //  I got here redirected URL instead i am expecting actual web site URLS.
    //
}
```

Above code simply call when DocumnetComplete event get fired.

Comment: DocumentComplete will be fired twice for this navigation: Once for google.co.in/url..., and once for the redirected URL (msdn.microsoft.com/...). What's your problem?

Comment: @RobW As per my observation DecomentComplete fired only once and my problem is simple the URLs getting from IHTMLDocumnet2 after DocumetComplete notification are Google redirected URLs not original URLs what we see on response page...So i want original URLs

Comment: Code? IE version? I got the expected URLs from the parameters and also from the IWebBrowser2 object (`get_locationURL`)

Comment: @RobW Please see the sample code snippet which i append with question

Comment: Ah.... You meant that you're collecting URLs from `<a>` elements in the Google result page, without navigating to it. When JavaScript is disabled, the search results in Google consists of URLs like `google.com/url?url=....`, so your code is working as expected.

Comment: @RobW Do you have any suggestion to modify above code to get actual URLs instead of redirected ones..Thanks in advance

Comment: Just parse the URL and extract the `url` parameter...

Comment: @RobW Yes using parser it will possible but In live HTML(using "Development Tools" F12) it shows actual URLs(Not redirected), Then why should my BHO not getting/collecting those URLs and if not possible then is there any other ways to collect those actual URLs without writing parser?

Comment: If you use view source, do you see `/url?...&url=...`? And you don't need to write any parser, there are plenty of URL/query string parsing libraries out there.

Comment: Yes in view source it shows `/url?...&url=...` but in live HTML(using F12) its shows actual URLs so whats difference? and see i am not interested in view source but more interested in live HTML so is there any other way to directly deal with live HTML?

Comment: With IE8, using F12, I also see <a> tags with correct (not redirected) URLs in the href attributes. You should get them with your code.

Comment: @manuell Yes i am also expecting that too but its not working, i think google changes URLs after DocumentComplete event using something like using JavaScript so the main problem is how to get that live HTML code from BHO?

Comment: Are you "logged" to google.com when doing your search?

Comment: Yes but didn't get according to my problem

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: No i was not logged at the time of searching. Ohhh sorry wrong interpretation.

Comment: Do you still have problems?

Comment: @manuell very very thanks for your follow up, Now i am getting the URLs but In DocumentComplete DISPID i get last loaded page URLs... Does this happening due to BHO loading order or any other issue?